# JavaScript noob lost with if statement

Tags: javascript

this is myFunctions code but it doesn't work. actually its beginner code cause i self teach what i can as i go. all variable are declare before the function

Original coded edited out.

it keeps going till all tubing size and weights from a table i have are filled in. it only works when i have 1 if statement. guess what i m asking is whats wrong with it. and is there an easier way to do this. i have more table for different things like casing of wellbore.

this won't work

```
<head>
    <title>Well Service Prevention</title>
    <script>
        var tubingSize;
        var tubingWeight;
        var tubingDisplacement;
        var tubingCapacity;
        function tubingTables(frm){
            if (frm.tubingSize.value == 50.8){
                tubingSize = 50.8
                tubingWeight = 5.06
                tubingDisplacement = 0.00065
                tubingCapacity = 0.001413
                alert("Tubing ID: " + tubingSize)
            }
            if (frm.tubingSize.value == 52.4){
                tubingSize = 52.4
                tubingWeight = 4.84
                tubingDisplacement = 0.000622
                tubingCapacity = 0.001554
                alert("Tubing ID: " + tubingSize)
            }
            if (frm.tubingSize.value == 60.3 && frm.tubingWeight.value == 5.95){
                tubingSize = 60.3
                tubingWeight = 5.95
                tubingDisplacement = 0.000765
                tubingCapacity = 0.00211
                alert("Tubing ID: " + tubingSize "Tubing Weight:" + tubingWeight)
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name=known>
        <h3>
            Enter Known
        </h3>
        <p>Tubing ID: <input type="number" name="tubingSize">
        <p>Tubing Weight: <input type="number" name="tubingWeight">
        <p>Tubing Displacement: <input type="number" name="tubingDisplacement">
        <p>Tubing Capacity: <input type="number" name="tubingCapacity">
        <input type="button" value="Debug" onclick="tubingTables(this.form)">
    </form>
</body>
```

remove last if statement it works.

```
<head>
    <title>Well Service Prevention</title>
    <script>
        var tubingSize;
        var tubingWeight;
        var tubingDisplacement;
        var tubingCapacity;
        function tubingTables(frm){
            if (frm.tubingSize.value == 50.8){
                tubingSize = 50.8
                tubingWeight = 5.06
                tubingDisplacement = 0.00065
                tubingCapacity = 0.001413
                alert("Tubing ID: " + tubingSize)
            }
            if (frm.tubingSize.value == 52.4){
                tubingSize = 52.4
                tubingWeight = 4.84
                tubingDisplacement = 0.000622
                tubingCapacity = 0.001554
                alert("Tubing ID: " + tubingSize)
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form name=known>
        <h3>
            Enter Known
        </h3>
        <p>Tubing ID: <input type="number" name="tubingSize">
        <p>Tubing Weight: <input type="number" name="tubingWeight">
        <p>Tubing Displacement: <input type="number" name="tubingDisplacement">
        <p>Tubing Capacity: <input type="number" name="tubingCapacity">
        <input type="button" value="Debug" onclick="tubingTables(this.form)">
    </form>
</body>
```

also working on getting a debugger in firefox right now. any sugestions?

Comment: Your first `if` statement uses `frm.tubingSize.value` all the others don't...

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean "it only works with 1 if statement" Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: Learn to use your browser's debugging tools. It'll be the best programming step you ever took.

Comment: ok. even with the .value added to the if conditions i can't get it to work. the first if statement works by its self, as soon as i add the second with the && neither of them work.

Comment: You might also be falling victim to the fact that floating point numbers don't always compare equal to each other. But we're going to have to get some more information about what is working and what isn't before we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are making some mistake. Here take a look

```
// frm seems to be a Javascript Object
// tubingSize is a property of frm and seems to be an object too since you are accessing value property of it.
if (frm.tubingSize.value == 52.4){
      tubingSize = 52.4
      tubingWeight = 4.84
      tubingDisplacement = 0.000622
      tubingCapacity = 0.001554
      alert("Tubing ID: " + tubingSize) //debug
}

// Since frm.tubingSize is an object. Either you should do .value here or correct your code in above if.
if (frm.tubingSize == 60.3 && frm.tubingWeight == 5.95){
      tubingSize = 60.3
      tubingWeight = 5.95
      tubingDisplacement = 0.000765
      tubingCapacity = 0.00211
      alert("Tubing ID: " + tubingSize "Tubing Weight:" + tubingWeight)
}
```

That's why your only one IF is working. You should probably use frm.tubingSize.value in other IFs too.